# Which ToolTip I can use to show data from database with asp.net? And how?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, tooltip

Basically, I need to show a ToolTip when mouseover in a LinkButton which is a column in a GridView. The GridView is showing Groups and I want the ToolTip to show the records related to those Groups (which are not included in the GridView datasource).

Any ideas on how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link extremely useful:

http://rndnext.blogspot.com/2009/02/jquery-ajax-tooltip.html

Even if I had a few problems whilst trying to implement it, the questions and answers at the bottom of the post were as helpful as the post itself.

Now I got it working smoothly! 100% recommended